# idea cant find xml, but The XML file is right here

Tags: java, spring, apache-dubbo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23AV6.png)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-provider.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-provider.xml] cannot be opened because it does not e[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oni0z.png)xist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The XML isn't in the place you think it is. Please share the exact location of that (show the code structure and the part that is loading this).